# Execute function if pause event fires

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, apache-cordova

I simply try to change the content of an element with id `output`, after the  the `pause` event fired.

```
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    function onDeviceReady() 
    {
        document.addEventListener("pause", test,false);
    }

    function test() 
    {
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "PAUSE";
    }
```

This works on desktop browser.

> The pause event fires when the native platform puts the application
>   into the background, typically when the user switches to a different
>   application.

But if i switch to another app on my mobile phone (windows phone), then it does not work? Is it because I did not added the platform `windows` to my project?

Comment: What is not working ?

Comment: The function is not executed.

Comment: @EdwardBlack Without adding windows platform, how did you manage to install the app on windows phone?